# TypeScript (JS) - Getting changed value from onchange function

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

What I'm trying to do is get the new value after an onchange event is triggered on an HTMLInputElement. I know I can get that by using element.value, however that wont work in the big picture. Please see the code below:

```
//This Works:
     elem.onchange = (ev: Event) => {
                    var newValue = (<HTMLInputElement>ev.srcElement).value; 
                    alert("Old: " + this._data[key] + ", New: " + newValue);
}

//Is there anyway I can get it to work like below? Currently I keep getting old values as new and old.
     elem.onchange = (ev: Event) => {
                    var attName = "checked"; //or "value"  for example
                    var newValue = ev.srcElement.getAttribute(attName); 
                    alert("Old: " + this._data[key] + ", New: " + newValue);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good question; I would guess that the internal `.value` changes before the HTML attribute, so you might not be able to force it to happen that way. What are you implying about the "big picture" and the need to use getAttribute?

Comment: Whoever down voted doesn't make sense. I show exactly what I have tried above. Just because you don't know the answer you should not down vote. Also if you have a question you can ask for clarification.

Comment: Attributes and values have a correlation in that an attribute may be the serialized representation of a value. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Hi Katana, This is just a simplified version of what I am trying to do. The big picture refers to my full solution. I would like to be able to use getAttribute so that I can get the changed values from checkboxes and radio buttons also.

Comment: This will not work. Use value instead of attributes for checkboxes. In fact use values for everything to avoid these issues.

Comment: @DonO Checkboxes and radio buttons have a `.checked` property, similar to text inputs' `.value` property. In my case, I wrote a function that can check the element's type to determine which to retrieve. For instance, `element.type === 'checkbox'`. I'm afraid I don't understand the downvote logic either - and people have a bad habit of downvoting without explaining what their problem with the question is (Especially since sometimes that "problem" is incorrect!)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `getAttribute("checked")` in order to tell if a checkbox is checked. You need to use the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/checked) property:

```
elem.onchange = function (ev) {
    var element = <HTMLInputElement>ev.srcElement,
        newValue: string | boolean;

    if (element.type === "checkbox") {
        newValue = element.checked;
    }
    else {
        newValue = element.value;
    }

    alert("Old: " + this._data[key] + ", New: " + newValue);
};
```

Comment: Thank you.
I was looking a way to get the value but unless you cast the element you can't get the attribute.